# How to check if global function exists in JS?

Tags: javascript

I got this global function function:

```
GlobalFunctions = {
      something: function() {

      }
};
```

I know how to check if a function exists with this:

```
if (typeof functionName == "function")
```

or even better:

```
if (typeof functionName === "function")
```

but those I have mentioned above still return the next error when I an trying to find out if a global function is valid:

```
if (typeof GlobalFunctions.something == "function")
```

gives this:

```
angular.js:12520 ReferenceError: GlobalFunctions is not defined
    at r.$scope.continueLogout (my-app.js:197)
    at b.$scope.logout (my-app.js:243)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13365), <anonymous>:4:209)
    at e (angular.js:23613)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:16152)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23618)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I have searched in google but only found solutions for function but not for global functions.

Hope thats clear enough, thanks.

Comment: really i dont understand why downvote.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: this is the code...

Comment: No it isn't. The error comes from angular.js which I assume isn't where you put that test. `typeof x` will never throw an "is not defined" error.

Comment: thats what ive written:
if (typeof Globalfunctions.something == "function") ive also edited this.

Comment: Well, `typeof functionName` is *very* different from `typeof GlobalFunctions.something`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164039/discussion-between-raz-and-jjj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
if (typeof GlobalFunctions != "undefined")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `var` / `let` / `const` key words when you declare the object.
And my guess is that your code runs with [`'use strict'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Without `strict mode` on, you can declare variables without the `var` key word and this will set the variable on the global object:

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
>   variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
>   creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work"

With `strict mode`:

```js
'use strict'
GlobalFunctions = {
      something: function() {

      }
};

if(GlobalFunctions) console.log('yeah');
```

Without `strict mode`:

```js
GlobalFunctions = {
      something: function() {

      }
};

if(GlobalFunctions) console.log('yeah');
```